# SQL Server Foreign Key Constraint References Invalid Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE _CLIENT
(
   client_id int ,
   client_name varchar(50),
   type varchar(50),
   constraint _CLIENT_pk PRIMARY KEY(client_id),
   constraint _CLIENT_ch CHECK (client_id>0),
   typee_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES CLIENT_TYPE(typee_id)
)

CREATE TABLE CLIENT_TYPE
(
   typee_id int NOT NULL,
   name_type varchar(50),
   constraint CLIENT_TYPE_pk PRIMARY KEY(typee_id)
)
```

The foreign key throws an error saying:

```
Foreign key 'FK__Number__Name__1CF15040' references invalid table 'Users.Name'
```

what's the wrong here?

Comment: There no reference to Users.Name in that code, which would suggest some other code is causing the error. Have you tried running your posted code in isolation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exact error message you are getting, but you have error in the current script and I think you mean this error:

> Foreign key 'FK___CLIENT__typee_i__55BFB948' references invalid table
>   'CLIENT_TYPE'.

You should first create `CLIENT_TYPE` table, so the script should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT_TYPE
(
    typee_id INT NOT NULL ,
    name_type VARCHAR(50) ,
    CONSTRAINT CLIENT_TYPE_pk PRIMARY KEY ( typee_id )
)

CREATE TABLE _CLIENT
(
    client_id INT ,
    client_name VARCHAR(50) ,
    type VARCHAR(50) ,
    CONSTRAINT _CLIENT_pk PRIMARY KEY ( client_id ) ,
    CONSTRAINT _CLIENT_ch CHECK ( client_id > 0 ) ,
    typee_id INT NOT NULL
                REFERENCES CLIENT_TYPE ( typee_id )
)
```

As a general rule, you should first create base tables and then tables which depend on those ones.